# Amcharts.js disabling my ammap's legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

so im using both ammap and amcharts in one page. the problem is, the amcharts.js always disabling my ammap's legend and make it invisible.

how do i solve this?

amcharts legend settings :

```
        "legend": {
        "width" : "100%",
        "maxRows": 1,
        "position": "bottom",
        // "useGraphSettings": true,
        "markerSize": 10,
        "align" : "center",

    },
```

ammap legend settings :

```
        "legend" : {
        "width": "30%",
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "marginRight": 27,
        "marginLeft": 27,
        "equalWidths": false,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0.2,
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#ffffff",
        "top": 450,
        "left": 0,
        "horizontalGap": 10,
        "data": [ {
            "title": "Negeri",
            "color": "#BF55EC",

            // "customMarker": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/car.png"
        }, {
            "title": "Swasta",
            "color": "#32C5D2",
            "border" : "#000000"
        } ],
    }
```

but i dont think the problem lies in my codes. whenever i commented out amcharts.js it's working again.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or a codepen showing your problem? I'm not seeing the problem on my end, though I had to comment out `top` and `useGraphSettings` in the map. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e1ccf9d26ee3cfc82b6f670bba02cc29) (link fixed)

Comment: whoa that's weird. do you think unrelated css and js files can affect the result? I wanted to use this [html map marker too](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/), but the marker is always at the top-left of the screen

Comment: anyway, here's the [link](https://codepen.io/puntodamar/pen/XqaBJj). thank you for your time <3

Comment: Make sure you're using `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` instead of `ammap.js` if you're including both charts and maps on the same page as amcharts.js and ammap.js override each other's methods, causing bugs. Markers work fine as well as you can see [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d03d7415408ba5162eb7b043ee9bc92a/?editors=0010).

Comment: what's the difference between those two?
yep it's fixed thanks.

Comment: `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` just extends `amcharts.js` to include map functionality so it requires `amcharts.js` to be included first. `amcharts.js` and `ammap.js` invidiually implement most of the same functions but in different ways, so if you include the two together things will break. charts + extension is the recommended approach for a chart+map page.

Comment: it's working. I forgot to say thank you :))

Comment: You're welcome!